# ADO recordset EOF and BOF not as expected

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

```
arrBand = array("6M","10M","12M","15M","17M","20M","30M","40M","60M","80M","160M")
```

The stored proc is

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableBand
WHERE UCall=[In_Call] And ACID=[In_CID] and BAND=[In_Band];
```

The following code always executes the "not" condition. For a given CRS("CID") there are only 2 rows in the database that have one of the array values, i.e. 6M and 10M.

```
for i = 0 to UBound(arrBand)
  ConnTemp.GetMode SanCall, CRS("Cid"), arrBand(i), BandRS
  if not BandRS.EOF and not BandRS.BOF then
    tmp = tmp + "<td style='width: 59px;'>" + arrBand(i) + "<input name='Ck'" +     arrBand(i) + "' type='checkbox' checked='checked'value='Y'/></td>"
  else
   tmp = tmp + "<td style='width: 59px;'>" + arrBand(i) + "<input name='Ck'" + arrBand(i) + "' type='checkbox'/></td>"
end if
BandRS.close
next
```

Comment: Without seeing your table data and the exact SQL statement being executed, it's hard to help.

Comment: The exact SQL statement is in the post. The table contains 3 columns, ACID, UCall, Band, all text. The data in row 1 is 1A0, nf4l, 6M. In row 2 it's  1A0, NF4L, 10M.

Comment: are you sure data is being returned and no errors are occurring?

Comment: Redfaced, I now see I was calling the wrong proc, should have been getBand. Having corrected that, now I get:    Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'UCall=[In_Call] And ACID=[In_CID] and BAND=[In_Band]'.

Comment: The query runs perfectly in Access.

Comment: Apparently it didn't like the field name "Band", even tho it ran in Access itself. I changed it to Bandx, and it's now working.

Comment: @Mike: you should post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: FYI, `BAND` is a [Jet 4.0 reserved keyword](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266).  The note at the beginning of the article mentions that the actual list of reserved words depends on how your run the query.  This explains why the query works in Access, but not from ADO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the field name "Band" is a reserved word, even tho the query ran in Access itself. I changed it to Bandx, and it's now working.